# JOOQ query to JOIN ON WITH clause

Tags: java, sql, jooq, with-clause

How can I write a JOOQ query to join on a field from a "with" clause?

For example, I've tried:

```
create.with("a").as(select(
                           val(1).as("x"),
                           val("a").as("y")
                   ))
      .select()
      .from(tableByName("a")
      .join(ANOTHER_TABLE)
          .on(ANOTHER_TABLE.ID.eq(tableByName("a").field("x")))
      .fetch();
```

However, as the compiler doesn't know the type of tableByName("a").field("x") it cannot resolve which eq() method to use. Given that I know the type, is there a way I can provide it explicitly? Or is there another approach I should take to join on a field from a "with" clause?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While I certainly agree with [flutter's answer being a more desireable path to a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44486088/521799) here, I'll just quickly add a response that answers your specific compilation error question.

There are three things that are wrong with your current join predicate:

```java
ANOTHER_TABLE.ID.eq(tableByName("a").field("x"))
```

1. [`DSL.tableByName()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#tableByName-java.lang.String...-) is deprecated. It is generally recommended to use [`table(Name)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#table-org.jooq.Name-) instead.
2. Such a dynamically constructed `Table` does not know of any of its `field()` references, thus `table(name("a")).field("x")` will return `null`
3. The compilation error is due to your `ID` reference being of type `Field<Integer>` (probably), and thus the [`Field.eq()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Field.html#eq-org.jooq.Field-) method expects a `Field<Integer>` argument as well. Without any knowledge about the type of your field `"x"`, the jOOQ API / Java compiler infers `Field<Object>`, which is invalid.

So, the solution would be to write:

```java
// field(Name, Class)
ANOTHER_TABLE.ID.eq(field(name("a", "x"), Integer.class))

// field(Name, DataType)
ANOTHER_TABLE.ID.eq(field(name("a", "x"), ANOTHER_TABLE.ID.getDataType()))
```

I.e. to use [`DSL.field(Name, Class<T>)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#field-org.jooq.Name-java.lang.Class-), or [`DSL.field(Name, DataType<T>)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#field-org.jooq.Name-org.jooq.DataType-) if you're using custom data type bindings / converters.

Answer (score 2):

What about declaring the CTE first?
[Explicit common table expressions](https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.4/manual/sql-building/sql-statements/with-clause/)

```
CommonTableExpression<Record2<Integer, String>> a =
  name("a").fields("x", "y").as(select(val(1), val("a")));

create.with(a)
      .select()
      .from(a)
      .join(ANOTHER_TABLE)
      .on(ANOTHER_TABLE.ID.eq(a.field("x")))
      .fetch();
```

If this does not work, you can always get the `DataType<?>` or the `Class<?>` via the `Field`, which you can get via the `Table`.

Comment: Thanks, but this still doesn't help the compiler to resolve which `eq()` overload to use. Lukas' answer of using the field(Name, Class) overload where the type is passed in does the trick.